# Full width across pages goes wrong with adjustwidth* of changepage package

Tags: adjustwidth, changepage

`adjustwidth*` (the starred-version) does not switch between even and odd pages. Do I mis-understand the `changepage` manual, or is it a bug?

The following screenshots show (a) the bottom of page 2 and the top of page 3 and (b) the bottom of page 3 and the top of page 4. Observe that the layout is correct on pages 2 and 4 but is incorrect on page 3.

[image]

...

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{adjustwidth*}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can replicate the issue you've come across, which is the apparent inability to switch the margin settings between even- and odd-numbered pages. I've taken the liberty of simplifying your sample code to focus it more on the issue at hand; feel free to revert.

Comment: @mico, i have the same problem with blindtext or lipsum. To see better, I put \color{red} before \begin and \color{black} after \end

Comment: Note that \adjustwidth doesn't actually change the margins but rather adjusts  \leftskip and \rightskip to overlap the margins.

Answer (score 2):

With th package tcolorbox

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668095/full-width-across-pages-goes-wrong-with-adjustwidth-of-changepage-package

    \usepackage{showframe,lipsum}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{breakable}

    \newlength{\mylength}
    \setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
    \tcbset{width=\linewidth+\mylength,colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white,
    if odd page*={grow to right by=\mylength}{grow to left by=\mylength}
    }


    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-8]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,notitle,boxrule=0pt,if odd page*={colback=red!50}{colback=yellow!50},colframe=blue!20]
        \lipsum[1-8]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could do it with paracol, but you would have to start with the large \textwidth and reduce it.  Flowfram would work, but is positioned relative to the page, not the text.